# Figure out which of my plugins is tanking Visual Studio 2010 performance

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a number of plugins that I use. Whenever I load a (~30 projects) solution in Visual Studio 2010, it will take on the order of 5-7 minutes to load. While loading, ProcMon shows that Visual Studio is enumerating what looks like pretty much the entire contents of my 3TB hard drive. How can I find out which plugin is causing this ? I have PerfWatson installed, but I don't know how to find the logs for it.

*EDIT*: This performance problem started well before I installed PerfWatson, and selectively disabling each one (and in combinations) has shown some improvement, but not to the level where Visual Studio should be (and is on other machines, even ones with slower hard drives, processors and motherboard buses). Believe it or not, I've actually done a fair bit of testing on this.

*EDIT 2*: This problem is a problem with Visual Studio itself, not any plugins. It occurs even when running the program with the `/SafeMode` flag and all plugins / extensions unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [SpyStudio](http://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/) which can show in Analysis -> Statistics and then 'By Module' the time and the number of operations that each module does.